# SQLでキーとなるデータがなければINSERTし、あれば該当キーのデータをUPDATEするような方法について

Tags: sql, csv, database

お世話になります。

今までも過去に何度も出ている質問と思いますが、過去ログでも見つからなかったので
質問いたします。

データベースの種類を問わず、ある既存のテーブルにCSVファイルをインポートする方法を
検討しています。

特定のフィールドにキーがあり、CSV側のデータがテーブル側のキーに該当しない場合は
新しい項目としてデータを追加(Import)、該当するキーがある場合はレコードの内容を
更新(UPDATE)させたいのですが、その方法を『全てのデータベースで
共通する方法』で行えればと思うのですが、そういった方法はありますでしょうか？

直接CSVと衝突させることができればベストなのですが、一度ダミーのテーブルにすべて
インポートしてから比較して…という方法でも構いません。

まだ知識も浅いもので、今のやり方だと、コード側で一行ずつデータを取り出してあるかどうかを
比較してからINSERTなりUPDATEなりをして…といったことをCSVの行数分ループさせて
いるのですが、これだとどうしても膨大な時間がかかってしまいます(15万件)。

データベースに依存しない、共通のSQLの範囲でこれらの作業を一つ二つのSQLで
行いたいのですが、そういった方法がありましたらご教授いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「データベースの種類を問わず」というのであれば、NoSQLも含まれるわけですよね。 NoSQLはSQL言語を使わずにデータの操作ができるデータベースなのですが、そういうものの存在を質問者はご存知ですか？

Comment: MERGEまたはUPSERTというステートメントがあるようです。[MERGE(SQL) - wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MERGE_(SQL)) 標準のSQL:2003にて定義されたようですが、サポート有無は製品によるのでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。NoSQLというのは、ツールなのでしょうか？記述してあるように、CSVのインポートから上記の処理を一発で行ってくれますか？それなら使用してみようと思います。

Comment: 実際の製品と処理をお探しなら、SQLServer2008以降用のこんな記事があります。[CSVファイルの登録処理について](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ja-JP/d77262ab-1c7e-4f70-bc78-ce9a62fe0e73/csv125011244912452125231239830331376822096629702123951238812356?forum=csharpgeneralja) と [SQL Server　OPENROWSET 関数の bulk オプションでテキストファイルを MERGE（UPSERT）処理](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/matu_tak/20091130/1259512848)

Answer (score 4):

そもそも、CSV(などDB外のデータ)をDBに取り込む「標準的な方法」が存在しません。この時点でDB固有の機能を使わざるを得ないので、「標準的な方法」にこだわるのは意味がありません。

・一行ずつ愚直に処理する
・テンポラリテーブルに一括で読み込んだあと、既存の表を更新+挿入
・DB次第では一発でできる？

のどれが効率的かは製品次第ですし、機能としては可能だとしても、運用上利用できない(例えば長時間テーブルロックがかかるのは都合が悪いとか)かもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。直接CSVから…というのには疑問だったため、まずはダミーテーブルに落としてと考えていたので、そこは目をつぶれるのですが、要は『Merge』といった方法が限定されているDBでしか行えないのが難点です。こんな機能はあってしかるべきだと思うので、標準のSQLで対応できて当たり前ではないかと思っていたのですが、そうもいかないようです。